# Replace header row from a Datatable with header row from another Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have two text files one Titles and one Data. The Titles contain the header row for the second, which is Data. I loaded them in 2 separate Datatables with the method:

```
private static DataTable SwitchColumnHeadersInDatatable(string file)
        {
            char Delimiter = '#';
            string whole_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            whole_file = whole_file.Replace('\n', '\r').Replace("\"", "");
            string[] Lines = whole_file.Split(new char[] { '\r' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            List<string[]> FileRows = Lines.Select(line =>
                line.Split(new[] { Delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToList();   //StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries   --> To remove nulls

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(FileRows[0].Select(col => new DataColumn() { ColumnName = col }).ToArray());

            FileRows.RemoveAt(0);
            FileRows.ForEach(row => dt.Rows.Add(row));

            return dt;
        }
```

The target is to replace the Data datatable Header Row (Column Names) with first row of Titles datatables (That hold Column Names)
I tried somethink like:

```
DataTable dtTitle = LoadTextInDatatable(txtLastRepTitle);
        DataTable dtData = LoadTextInDatatable(txtLastRepData);

        dtTitle.AsEnumerable().Take(1).CopyToDataTable(dtData, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

But can't find a way to specify the Row index(0) to paste in Data table. (And don't think is the best approach as well).  Also need to specify that on titles are some extra fields that will need to be removed. ("title1"#"Title2"#"Title3"#"type1"#"type2"#"type3" -> Only need the Title and the types to be removed)

Comment: Why two tables?  First read title into table.  Then file with 2nd file and remove at index 1 (not zero).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion #jdweng. Can you give a short hint\example on "file with 2nd file" ? I'm afraid I don't understand that

Comment: What is `SwitchColumnHeadersInDatatable` versus `LoadTextInDataTable`? Can you re-write "And now I want to replace" which seems wrong or maybe backwards to me?

Comment: Changed the method name (is the same) and re-write that part NetMage. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ with `IEnumerable` instead of processing everything in-memory. Read the titles from one file and the data from the other file:

```
private static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadNonEmptyLinesUnquoteAndSplit(string file, char delimiter) =>
    File.ReadLines(file).Where(l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).Select(l => l.Replace("\"", "").Split(delimiter));

private static DataTable LoadDataTable(string titlePath, string dataPath) {
    char Delimiter = '#';
    var TitleRow = ReadNonEmptyLinesUnquoteAndSplit(titlePath, Delimiter).Skip(1).First();
    var DataRows = ReadNonEmptyLinesUnquoteAndSplit(dataPath, Delimiter).Skip(1);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(TitleRow.Select(col => new DataColumn() { ColumnName = col }).ToArray());

    foreach (var dataRow in DataRows)
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);

    return dt;
}
```